# How to get the previous applications launched automatically after a reboot?

Tags: boot, configuration, kde, session

In the past, after a reboot, I used to get the same applications I had running launched automatically, with the same files opened.

With Manjaro/Arch I cannot get the same behaviour. Is there any setting I can switch to get it?

The desktop environment I am using is KDE, in case this is important.

In the "Desktop Session - System Settings Module" dialog, the "Restore previous session" option is already ticked, but is ignored. The behaviour is the one corresponding to the "Start with an empty session" option.

So, my questions are:

1. Is there anything else I can do from KDE to let the system know I want my session to be saved and reloaded after a reboot?
2. Is there a configuration file I can manually modify for the same purpose (probably the same one KDE modifies on its own).

Version info:
Manjaro 18.1.4
KDE Plasma 5.17.80
Linux Kernel 5.4.3

Comment: @jsotola - Sorry, I cannot see what is missing. Maybe you can help...

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using on arch/manjaro? So it's working on KDE and not on another one? Or do both the working OS and the non-working OS have KDE?

Comment: @rudib - The second; I always used KDE, and I am having this issue only with Arch/Manjaro.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly would be going on there then, but you could try checking if the ksmserver is working as expected by running `qdbus org.kde.ksmserver /KSMServer org.kde.KSMServerInterface.sessionList`. Which greeter are you using on Majaro?

Comment: @Pietro please consider updating your post to make it clearer on which de you are having the problem and where it is working. Also some version information and the command results could help.

Comment: @rudib - From the `qdbus` command, I get: `default` 
`saved at previous logout`

Comment: @rudib - I expanded my question.

Comment: I wanted to recommend you manually saving the session, rebooting and manually restoring it afterwards - for debugging. But unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an official way to restore sessions manually yet: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497360/manually-restore-saved-session-files-on-kde-using-qdbus-command

Comment: But you could try: `sudo cat /var/log/messages | grep ksmserver` to see if there are any errors realted to `ksmserver`.

Comment: @rudib - Sorry for my late reply. I have no `messages` file in that directory. Trying with `sudo cat /var/log/* | grep ksmserver` I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I am not the only one with this issue.

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kde-session-is-not-saved/138812

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/plasma-sessions/109404/3